# Proof Help involving continuity and the FTC

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is a continuous function, then $$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_x^b f(t)dt\right)= -f(x).$$
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using the properties of the integral as in the other answer, we write

$$ F(x)=\int_{b}^{x}f(t) dt \implies F(x+h)= \int_{b}^{x+h}f(t) dt= \int_{b}^{x}f(t) dt + \int_{x}^{x+h}f(t) dt $$

Now, we have
$$ \left|\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}-f(x)\right| = \left|\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t) dt - \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(x) \right| $$

$$\left|\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}-f(x)\right| = \left|\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}(f(t)-f(x)) dt  \right| \leq \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}|f(t)-f(x)| dt $$

$$ x<t<x+h  $$

Use the continuity of the function $f$ on the right hand side of the above inequality to finish the proof.

Comment: Did you reverse the upper and lower limits on purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\int_{x}^{b} f(t)dt=-\int_{b}^{x}f(t)dt$